# Configured Python Script as Service doesn't run on Startup

Tags: python, boot, services

I created a service to run my python program at Raspberry Startup. But the program doesn't execute.

My Service File:

```
[Unit]
Description =Serviço para iniciar o Gateway
After= multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
User=pi
Group=pi
WorkingDirectory = /home/pi/WebSite
ExecStart=/home/pi/WebSite/env/bin/python gateway.py > gateway.log 2>&1

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

If  a type sudo systemctl restart gateway.service ,the program runs normally, but at the startup it doesn'work.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you enabled it to start at startup via `sudo systemctl enable gateway.service`?

Comment: Yes! I do this.

Comment: Anything in `sudo journalctl -xe -u gateway.service` directly after boot before you've started the application manually?

Comment: Read **COMMAND LINES** in `man systemd.service`, specifically the paragraph which begins *"This syntax is..."*, includes the phrase *"Specifically, redirection using..."* and ends *"...are not supported."*.

Comment: @tobyd the output for this is:
-- no entries --

if a type sudo systemclt status gateway.service, returns me, enaled and
"Active: inactive (dead)". Is there any place to view any log?

Comment: I think @goldilocks is on the money here, drop the log redirection, output should end up in the journal anyway. Just have the execution as this `ExecStart=/home/pi/WebSite/env/bin/python gateway.py` and update the systemd files with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: You *can* redirect the output w/ `StandardOutput=` and/or `StandardError=`.  Those are documented in `man systemd.exec` (as opposed to `.service`, `.unit`, etc.; `apropos systemd` is worth a quick look).

Answer (score 5):

Systemd services aren't executed by a shell, and although `man systemd.service` notes the syntax for the various `Exec___` directives is "inspired by shell syntax", it also notes:

> **redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>",** pipes using "|",
>          running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax **are not supported.**

So you can see there is a problem there.  I don't know if that will necessarily mean the service wasn't run, but it will mean it won't log to where you want it to log (see the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` options in `man systemd.exec` for that).

Of course, this implies it can still be run manually:

> If a type sudo systemctl restart gateway.service ,the program runs normally

So likely the spurious redirection is just being ignored, and not the main problem.

This just seems wrong:

```
[Unit]
After= multi-user.target

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

If you have reason to believe this should work, fair enough.  If it is just something you decided upon, I would use something other than `multi-user.target` in `After`, e.g., `local-fs.target` or `networking.target` (check to make sure those are in use with `systemctl status ____` first).

By the way, you do not mention doing this:

```
sudo systemctl enable [my.service]
```

Which you must do if you want it run at boot.  You can also check after boot to see what happened:

```
systemctl status [my.service]
```

There should be some clue there.  Also, every time you change the service file you will need to use `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.

Finally, you may want to change the type of the service to either `simple` or `oneshot`, depending on whether this is a persistent, long-running program (`simple`) or something that just configures something quickly then exits (`oneshot`).

Comment: I try all options in After parameter and change Type to simple.

output of systemctl status gateway.service:

 gateway.service - Serviço para iniciar o Gateway no boot do Raspberry
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gateway.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: inactive (dead)
   
 Curiously, if a type "sudo systemctl start gateway.service" the program works fine. I can't understand.
 So, the service not starting, and i don't know why.

Comment: It might help if you went into more detail (in the question) about what the python script does.